# Error controller not hit when using httpErrors in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am struggling to setup the `httpErrors` section correctly in my `web.config` to capture both `ASP.NET MVC errors` and `IIS errors`. I am getting 403 status codes and blank pages. I am testing with `404` errors by typing incorrect URLS and file names in the URL, for example:

```
www.mywebsite.com/test
www.mywebsite.com/test.html
```

I am using the latest version of `ASP.NET MVC 5`. This web application is running on `IIS 7.5` with an application pool using `integrated mode`.

This is what my `web.config` looks like at the root of the application (this is all that I currently have):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>

    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
            <remove statusCode="404" />
            <remove statusCode="500" />
            <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
            <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>

    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <!-- ...and so forth... -->
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

My `global.asax.cs` file:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        // Break point has been set here for testing purposes
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        {
            // Break point has been set here for testing purposes
        }
    }
}
```

My error controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Break point has been set here for testing purposes
        Response.StatusCode = 500;

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Forbidden()
    {
        // Break point has been set here for testing purposes
        Response.StatusCode = 403;

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        // Break point has been set here for testing purposes
        Response.StatusCode = 404;

        return View();
    }
}
```

They have their corresponding views in the `Views` folder.

My break points are never hit in my error controller. I don't understand why? I have looked at many examples on Stackoverflow and this is how every suggests that I do it. When would the break points not be reached given my code? All that happens is a 403 error status and a BLANK white page. The break points in `Application_Error()` and `Application_EndRequest()` are hit, but not the break points in the error controller.

There is code that I can write in `Application_Error()` and `Application_EndRequest()` that lets me set the error controller and action method, but why do that if I can use the web.config? This should also work?

Comment: Can you check the URL flow in fiddler, I've implemented same thing in my sample application, and for me its working fine for 404, make sure you have not implemented any exception filters.

Comment: The status codes in Fiddler also shows 404 and I have no filters added. Where would I check this? I created a new empty MVC web app for this. If I change it to display html static pages for the errors then it works 100% correct. When I use the controller then it displays blank.

Comment: @BrendanVogt I'm having exactly the same problem. The key similarity is the 403 Forbidden HTTP response with a blank page when triggering the 404 ExecuteURL. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Man, you have mentioned statusCode as 404 then how can you expect as 200 OK ? :)

just remove `Response.StatusCode = 404;` line from action method

Bellow code should work

```
 public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

[image: Check this image. Working example]

Comment: At this point it doesn't matter because it doesn't enter this controller at all. I have a break point set here which is not reached. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Check my code in above image, this what exactly I did and its all working for me.
that must be some conflict with your routes, can you show me your routeConfig.cs file ?

Comment: Send me your sample app please? What version of IIS are you using? Version of ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5.1,MVC 5, IIS 7.5.7600.16385,
you may share your sample app I'll verify for the issue

Comment: I am running my app under IIS 7.5. You're not, you're using IIS Express. I created a new project and ran it like you and it worked fine. It seems to be an IIS issue/permission when using local IIS.

Comment: I've tried on IIS also, make sure you've not configured 404 page in IIS.

Comment: How can I send you my solution for you to check?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65211/discussion-between-moksh-shah-and-brendan-vogt).